# Cannot wait for the application to load after login

Tags: javascript, cypress

[image]

1. Log in after accessing the local test server.
2. After the login is successful, the errors occur on the console.

[image]

How do you solve it like a bug that appears because you can not load the functions after clicking the login button?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your question and help us to help you please read the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Finally its always a good  choice to add an [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Code in images is bad).

Comment: The first error is a syntax error with the `)` in `common/sheet/ibsheet.js`. Fix that first then see if you still have problems.